# Ignoring invalid values in Jackson, using spring

Tags: android, json, spring, date, jackson

I use the Spring framework to receive a JSON from a GET request. Everything worked just great, until a wrong value was put in the DB and this happens:

> 02-25 14:46:04.035: E/AndroidRuntime(12271):
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from
>   String value '-3600': not a valid representation (error: Failed to
>   parse Date value '-3600': Can not parse date "-3600": not compatible
>   with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
>   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",
>   "yyyy-MM-dd"))

How do i set up Jackson to ignore not readable/parseble values? i rather have null or so than that my complete json parsing fails...

here is my object i try to parse to, as you can see i tried to ignore properties with jsonignoreproperties in my code.

receipt:

```
public class Receipt {

    public String categories;


    @JsonProperty("expiration_date")
    public Date expirationDate;

    public String image1;

    public String image2;
(..  more properties, getters and setters ..)
```

And how i try to parse :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


    // instellen dat de converter ongedefineerde parameters negeert
    HttpMessageConverter customconver = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) customconver).getObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); //here the ignore unknown

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(customconver);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    try {
    // GET Request
    ResponseEntity<ReceiptMessage> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlPath, HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,ReceiptMessage.class);
```

keep in mind that BEFORE the -3600 value my parser worked fine, so there is no problem.

Is there a way to ignore these kind of errors?

Answer (score -1):

There is a setting on the `ObjectMapper` called `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`. That causes dates to be serialized as longs instead of strings, so disable it to get strings. You should most definitely read this: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

If you don't want to do that, to ignore a field based on some logic, just add a setter for the date field that takes a long and parse it yourself. You will probably need to annotated it with `@JsonSetter("expiration_date")` so Jackson knows to pass it in there.

Lastly, the Java date/calendar APIs are generally acknowledged to be completely horrible and should be avoided in every case possible. If you are using Java 8, the new date/time apis are much better. If you are pre-Java 8, use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). There is even a special Jackson module for handling it.